# Pixel shifting when converting PDF into image files

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I am using PDFBox to convert PDF documents into images.
But on some pages, a small amount of content are not rendered consistently. It seems like that small area is shifting a little bit (1-3 pixels). 
Here is the code:

```
document = PDDocument.load(pdfFile);
list = document.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();

for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    PDPage temp = list.get(i);
    BufferedImage image = temp.convertToImage(BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB, 150);
    File outputfile = new File(fileName + "_" + (i + 1) + ".png");
    ImageIOUtil.writeImage(image, outputfile.getAbsolutePath(), 150);
    //ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", outputfile);
}
```

Can anyone advice on how to solve this?

I got the difference by comparing the created image with the expected image pixel by pixel. There are other contents on the page but only a small part is shifting.

The link to the created, diff, expected images are here:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/mii7lo3dsvi0kmx/AABNWZ7lbdgHkSQw4RTm1IDoa?dl=0

Please advice on how to solve it!
Thank you!

Comment: Can you share a sample PDF and image to illustrate and reproduce?

Comment: I do not have enough reputation to post Images yet.

Comment: Simply share the PDF and the image via a file sharing service (e.g. public shares on Google drive or Dropbox) and post the URLs here.

Comment: Added the link.
Thank you so much @mkl!

Comment: I missed the PDF itself.

Comment: I've started looking into this. Quite interestingly the formulas in question are contained in form Xobjects with non-trivial matrices counteracted by the CTM. So there are enough manipulations to ignore... ;)

Comment: How did you create your *expected image*? It looks to me as if the PDFBox output respects the PDF content more than the *expected image* does.

Comment: Hello @mkl, thank you for continuously helping

Comment: The expected image is created in the same way from expected pdf. 
I have added the expected pdf into the folder.

Comment: I'm a bit confused: The difference already is in the source PDFs, so obviously the images generated by PDFBox should differ, too. Now what is the issue after all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Comparing the images

The critical region for this issue contains two formulas. These regions on the OP's images look like this:

> expected formula appearance:
>
> [image: expected formula appearance]

and

> created formula appearance
>
> [image: created formula appearance]

The difference is that the font sizes differ slightly, they are expected larger than they are created.

### Comparing the original PDFs in Adobe Acrobat

After the OP provided the source PDFs for those images, an analog image export could be made using Adobe Acrobat. The result:

> expected formula appearance, rendered by Acrobat
>
> [image: expected formula appearance]

and

> created formula appearance, rendered by Acrobat
>
> [image: created formula appearance]

Here, too, one can see the difference...

The letters and numbers differ substantially from above because the fonts in question are not embedded, and Acrobat uses a different actual font program.

But one font is embedded, the symbol font with the mathematical signs. So these symbols can be compared more strictly. Furthermore the line in the fraction is generated using vector graphics, independent of font replacement, too. Comparing the placement of these parts in relation to each other, one sees that Acrobat and PDFBox render them identically for the same source (with identical differences for the different source PDFs).

### Comparing the original PDFs internally

Indeed, the source PDFs differ. The formulas are drawn using form Xobjects, and while the internals of the page contents of the pages in the two documents otherwise are very similar (some minor changes but font sizes are identical), the font sizes in the Xobjects differ.

So it looks like a post-processor applied to the PDF has some bugs when processing form Xobjects.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!
What can I do to solve the problem?
Please advice

Comment: There is no problem. You have different input documents, so images rendered from them are different. If someone tells you they are not different, that person is not telling the truth.

Comment: Thank you so much! @mkl I will look into that.